# Docker: how do I find localhost's password on Windows 8.1

Tags: docker

I am running boot2docker start on a Windows PC and it gives me the following status.

> starting ...
>
> Waiting for VM and Docker Daemon to start...
>
> .docker@localhosts's password:

I tried to enter my laptop's password, but the cursor just sits and blinks. What password should I be typing at this prompt?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [boot2docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/):

> the username for the boot2docker default user is `docker` and the password is `tcuser`